OMNET++ simulation : Class not found perhaps its code was not linked in
I'am having a issue with omnet++ when running my first project and I don't get where the problem is

the error is : <!> Class "BaseStation" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel() -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) SimulationNetwork (id=1), during network setup

I verified BaseStation calls are all fine, but I cant get where is the error.
It would be great if you can help me, it will really save my life.
Thank you in advance.
I have 3 ned files : Node.ned, BaseStation.ned and Network.ned :
Node.ned :
package _6g_simulation;

simple Node {
    parameters:
        int id;
        @display("i=device/laptop");
    gates:
        inout inoutg[];
}


BaseStation.ned :
package _6g_simulation;

simple BaseStation {
    parameters:
        @display("i=device/server");
    gates:
        inout inoutg[];
}


Network.ned :
package _6g_simulation;
import _6g_simulation.BaseStation;
import _6g_simulation.Node;

network SimulationNetwork
{
    submodules:
        basestation: BaseStation {
            @display("p=40,111");
        }
        edgeNode[5]: Node {
            @display("p=150,38");
        }
        endUser[10]: Node {
            @display("p=241,64");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        // Connect base station to edge nodes
        for i=0..4 {
            basestation.inoutg[i] <--> edgeNode[i].inoutg[0];
        }
        // Connect edge nodes to end users
        for i=0..9 {
            edgeNode[i % 5].inoutg[0] <--> endUser[i].inoutg[0];
        }
}

omnetpp.ini :
[General]
network = _6g_simulation.SimulationNetwork

Basestation.cc:
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class BaseStation : public cSimpleModule {
  protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(BaseStation);

void BaseStation::initialize() {
    EV << "BaseStation initialized" << endl;
    // Initialization code here
}

void BaseStation::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
    EV << "Handling message at BaseStation" << endl;
    // Message handling code here
    delete msg;
}


My expectation is to run the simulation without any problem and I can see the nodes and the base station network on

Recommend removing the C++ tag as there is nothing that a C++ programmer who doesn't also know Omnet can do to help you.

Could you edit the question and add C++ code of BaseStation?

thank you for you comment, I have updated the question with BaseStation.cc code.

@oumaima
Ensure that Define_Module(BaseStation); is correctly placed in BaseStation.cc, and verify that BaseStation.cc is included in your makefile or IDE project settings for compilation. Clean and rebuild your project to ensure all changes are compiled properly. If using a makefile, confirm it has a line like sources += BaseStation.cc. #omnet++
